# Using iPhone as iBeacon Transmitter

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ibeacon

I'm trying to set up my iPhone to broadcast an iBeacon signal for another iPhone to pick up.  The iPhone that's supposed to pick up the signal is working, but I can't get the other iPhone to broadcast the signal.

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/location/how-to-make-an-iphone-transmit-an-ibeacon

And here's my code:

```
import CoreBluetooth
import CoreLocation

class iBeaconTransmission: NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

    var localBeacon: CLBeaconRegion!
    var beaconPeripheralData: NSDictionary!
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!

    func initLocalBeacon() {
        if localBeacon != nil {
            stopLocalBeacon()
        }

        let localBeaconUUID = "placeholder"
        let localBeaconMajor: CLBeaconMajorValue = 123
        let localBeaconMinor: CLBeaconMinorValue = 456

        let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: localBeaconUUID)!
        localBeacon = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: localBeaconMajor, minor: localBeaconMinor, identifier: "placeholder")

        self.beaconPeripheralData = self.localBeacon.peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower(nil)
        self.peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
    }

    func stopLocalBeacon() {
        peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
        peripheralManager = nil
        beaconPeripheralData = nil
        localBeacon = nil
    }

    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        print("Peripheral Manager")
        if peripheral.state == .PoweredOn {
            print("Transmitting")
            peripheralManager.startAdvertising(beaconPeripheralData as! [String: AnyObject]!)
        } else if peripheral.state == .PoweredOff {
            peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
        }
    }
}
```

Another note, location services is already set to always authorized.

"Peripheral Manager" is also never being printed, so the function that's in isn't being called for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually using `placeholder` as the uuid? And what debugging have you done.

Comment: No I'm using an actual UUID.  I put placeholder in for the purposes of posting to stack overflow.  I've place breakpoints at the beginning of each function and stepped through, and the only thing I noticed is func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) is not being called.  I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Have you requested location authorisation?

Comment: Yes.  I've aloud it to always track my location on my device.

Comment: Call start advertising immediately, it shouldn't work but the error may offer some illumination

Comment: Here's what I got: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: For some reason moving the code into a view controller worked.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  I moved the code into a view controller and called initLocalBeacon() in the viewDidLoad function.